# Audio works in Spark-ar but not in Instagram

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I've designed a filter which displays some images and plays some audio.

It works well in spark-ar studio, but once exported to Instagram (either directly or through a test link) the images appear, but the sounds don't!

The sound files are .m4a mono channel. Spark-ar studio tells me everything is correct.

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem. Test filter plays audio correctly in Spark. Testing in IG through the Spark AR Hub demo video, it picks up sounds through mic but doesn't play audio. Video sound is on when tested in IG. .m4a mono channel at 44.1kHz, acc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the audio is sampled at 44.1kHz. Convert it in itunes if you can

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to codec from alac (default of m4a) to aac.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Make sure your settings are:

**.m4a mono channel at 44.1kHz, acc**

Re-export your file and upload to Spark AR Hub.

Then SAVE at the top menu
[image]

You can then test your file using *Capture Video* under the *Demo Video* section.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

to enable sound,  play when you are recording you have to Go to your scene and find Microphone. Then, check to disable it. It should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

i had same problem,i just change the audio file and now problem solved!

Comment: You changed the audio file to what? a bit more information would help others